# Parallel request historical options chain prices / Last known price in IBrokers (R)

Tags: r, concurrent-programming, algorithmic-trading, stockquotes, ibrokers

I am trying to create **Current** Options Chain (options per strike, per expiration) for a ticker.

```
library(IBrokers)    
tws <- twsConnect()
# Lets say only Call prices
AA <- reqContractDetails(tws, twsOption(local="", right="C", symbol="AAPL"))
```

Native implementation with **`snapshot`** is too slow:

```
reqMktData(tws, AA[1:2], snapshot = TRUE)
```

It waits around **`11 sec`** per contract (Current number of Contracts is 626)

---

Another implementation:

```
snapShot <- function (twsCon, eWrapper, timestamp, file, playback = 1, ...)
{
  if (missing(eWrapper))
    eWrapper <- eWrapper()
  names(eWrapper$.Data$data) <- eWrapper$.Data$symbols
  con <- twsCon[[1]]
  if (inherits(twsCon, "twsPlayback")) {
    sys.time <- NULL
    while (TRUE) {
      if (!is.null(timestamp)) {
        last.time <- sys.time
        sys.time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(readBin(con,
                                                      character(), 2), collapse = " "), timestamp))
        if (!is.null(last.time)) {
          Sys.sleep((sys.time - last.time) * playback)
        }
        curMsg <- .Internal(readBin(con, "character",
                                    1L, NA_integer_, TRUE, FALSE))
        if (length(curMsg) < 1)
          next
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, format(sys.time,
                                                 timestamp), file, ...)
      }
      else {
        curMsg <- readBin(con, character(), 1)
        if (length(curMsg) < 1)
          next
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, timestamp,
                   file, ...)
        if (curMsg == .twsIncomingMSG$REAL_TIME_BARS)
          Sys.sleep(5 * playback)
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    evalWithTimeout(
    while (TRUE) {
      socketSelect(list(con), FALSE, NULL)
      curMsg <- .Internal(readBin(con, "character", 1L,
                                  NA_integer_, TRUE, FALSE))
      if (!is.null(timestamp)) {
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, format(Sys.time(),
                                                 timestamp), file, ...)
      }
      else {
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, timestamp,
                   file, ...)
      }
      if (!any(sapply(eWrapper$.Data$data, is.na)))
        return(do.call(rbind, lapply(eWrapper$.Data$data,
                                     as.data.frame)))
    }, timeout=5, onTimeout="warning")
  }
} 

reqMktData(tws, AA[1:20], eventWrapper=eWrapper.data(20),CALLBACK=snapShot)
```

It avoids waiting ( 11 secs ).

But this doesn't work if there is no real-time data or markets are closed.

So, I want to get only the last known price even if markets are closed.

**This is my pseudo-solution:**

```
reqHistoricalData(tws, AA[[1]]$contract, whatToShow='BID', barSize = "1 min", duration = "60 S")
```

**Is there a way to parallelize this solution so it will call for historical price of several contract?**

Currently it spends around **`2.3 seconds`** per contract, while previous solution is able to get 20-30 contracts with the same time spent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `reqMktData()`, consider using **`reqRealTimeBars()`** with a variable containing your list of contracts to do what you want without the limitations of `reqHistoricalData()`.

Real Time Bars is a query for streaming Historical Data, the data is relayed back from the same servers that provide Historical Data.

Comment: Unfortunelty **reqRealTimeBars** seem to suffer from the same problem as **reqMktData()** 

As far as I can see no answer if being provided when markets are closed. While, I would like it report the last known price if markets are not open.

Comment: Have you tried using useRTH?  reqHistoricalData(tws, AA[[1]]$contract, whatToShow='BID', barSize = "1 min", duration = "60 S", useRTH = 0)